# Error: An error occurred while saving the entity changes in .NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm getting this error when I'm posting data to my API:

```
An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_OrderLine_Order_OrderID". 

The conflict occurred in database "AnimimoMicroservicesNewOrderServiceContext-feca99ec-8feb-4680-b1f5-f1a32825a8c1", table "dbo.Order", column 'OrderID'.
```

This is the HttpPost method where I'm posting my model to the database:

```
// POST: api/Orders
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrder(PostOrderDTO postOrderDto)
        {

            var order = new Order(postOrderDto.Identifier, postOrderDto.Customer);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);

            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            _context.Order.Add(order);

            var basket = await GetBasketItems(postOrderDto.Identifier);
            var newOrderId = order.OrderID;

            foreach (var item in basket.Items)
            {
                var orderLine = new OrderLine
                {
                    OrderID = newOrderId,
                    ProductId = item.ProductId,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity
                };

                _context.OrderLine.Add(orderLine);
            };

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetOrder", new { id = order.OrderID }, order);
        }
```

The 'OrderID' is auto-generated when posting to Order but I need same generated OrderID to be posted and saved in OrderLine as well, here is what my Order database looks like:
[OrderDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzK0w.png)
So the OrderID that is generated when I post and save to Order is what I'm trying to get to my OrderLine DB which looks like this in my database:
[OrderLineDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbkTI.png)

It only says NULL, then I tried the following code above in the POST method to post the OrderID but got the error as stated above, I'm trying to resolve this

This is my Order.cs model:

```
public class Order
    {
        public Order(int orderID, string identifier, string customer)
        {
            OrderID = orderID;
            Identifier = identifier;
            Customer = customer;
        }

        public Order(string identifier, string customer)
        {
            Identifier = identifier;
            Customer = customer;
        }

        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }

        public string Customer { get; set; }

        //[NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<OrderLine> Items { get; set; } = new List<OrderLine>();
    }
```

The 'OrderID' in Order.cs model is a foreign key to the OrderLine table which looks like this:

```
public class OrderLine
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I fix this? I want the generated OrderID of my Order table to be posted to my OrderLine table with the same Post method but I only got the error as stated above, can I fix this? Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding the order you did not save your changes. This means that the order object does not have an id yet. If you save after `_context.Order.Add(order);` and before adding the id to the orderline this wil be resolved.

Comment: You mean that I should move await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); to after                 _context.OrderLine.Add(orderLine);
 ? Thanks for helping out

Comment: No to after `_context.Order.Add(order);`, then the id is in the `order` object and you can access it.

Comment: So should I have two _context.SaveChangesAsync ? one for Order and one for OrderLine?

Comment: In this case, yes. If you dont persist it, `var newOrderId = order.OrderID;` will be null since it does not have a value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix the navigaion properties

```
public class OrderLine
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
       public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

         public  virtual Order Order { get; set; }
        public virtual Product { get; set; }
       
    }
```

and  in the code remove  _context.Order.Add(order);

```
            var basket = await GetBasketItems(postOrderDto.Identifier);
  
            foreach (var item in basket.Items)
            {
                var orderLine = new OrderLine
                {
                    Order = order,
                    ProductId = item.ProductId,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity
                };

                _context.OrderLine.Add(orderLine);
            };

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

and just because of curiosity, what is this for ?

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);
 var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out man, but the thing is I want to add to Order as well, can I still do this?

Comment: The last part is for serializing the object but I don't know otherwise really :/

Comment: @NMNamu "I want to add to Order as well". It will be added automatically.