# Return OrderID after Post instead of Entire Post

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm trying to achieve this in my API after posting to my API as a 201 Status Code Return:

```
{
   orderId: "4"
}
```

But instead I'm getting this back after I POST:

```
{
    "orderID": 4,
    "identifier": "Udacity",
    "customer": "Assassin's Creed",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "orderID": 4,
            "productId": 5000,
            "quantity": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code for returning after POST:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrder(PostOrderDTO postOrderDto)
        {

            var order = new Order(postOrderDto.Identifier, postOrderDto.Customer);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);

            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            _context.Order.Add(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var basket = await GetBasketItems(postOrderDto.Identifier);
            var newOrderId = order.OrderID;

            foreach (var item in basket.Items)
            {
                var orderLine = new OrderLine
                {
                    OrderID = newOrderId,
                    ProductId = item.ProductId,
                    Quantity = item.Quantity
                };

                _context.OrderLine.Add(orderLine);
            };

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetOrder", new { id = order.OrderID }, order);
        }
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Do I do this?

```
return CreatedAtAction("GetOrder", new { id = order.OrderID });
```

I don't that worked the last time I tried, thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this code

```
         [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostOrder(PostOrderDTO postOrderDto)
        {
            .... your code

            return Ok( new { id = order.OrderID } );
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, God bless you my friend

Comment: You are welcome! Don' t forget to accept my another answer too.

Comment: Yes I accepted it! But unfortunately I can't upvote it because of the low reputation I have, otherwise I would :)

Comment: @NMNamu thanks, but i mean this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608833/error-an-error-occurred-while-saving-the-entity-changes-in-net